# Java RMI, Tomcat problem!

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi

I am learning about Java RMI and have an example code to show how RMI can be used to pass objects to another virtual machines over a network.

Here are the classes and code I am using;

```
//interface
    import java.rmi.*;

public interface MyRemote extends Remote
{ 
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;

}

//My Remote Implementation Class
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class MyRemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote
{
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Server says, 'Hey' ";
    }

    public MyRemoteImpl() throws RemoteException
    {

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
            Naming.rebind("Remote Hello", service);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//My Remote Client Class
import java.rmi.*;

public class MyRemoteClient
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        new MyRemoteClient().go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        try{
            MyRemote service = (MyRemote) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/Remote Hello");

            String s = service.sayHello();

            System.out.println(s);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid URL String: rmi://127.0.0.1/Remote Hello which I know is due to the 'Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/Remote Hello")' code in the last class.

I have installed tomcat and tried placing the files in a directory, trying to get it to run on my local machine but I have had no joy.

I have created a JAR file of my project and tried placing that in a directory also and still no luck. I have heard about war files but currently the book I am learning from hasnt come to that yet...

Any tips on how I can get around this without the exception being called? Am I placing the files incorrectly in Tomcat? I have placed them in my C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps directory.

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Thanks for the advice, the String exception seems to have gone away but now I am lumbered with this.

java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at MyRemoteClient.go(MyRemoteClient.java:13)
    at _*SHELL57.run(*_SHELL57.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:623)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:316)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:164)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:154)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:352)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:569)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:416)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:199)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)

Comment: Can you try it without the space in `Remote Hello`

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1. Change the name of the remote object to something without a space.
2. Are you running the server code first?

Answer (score 2):

What does Tomcat have to do with RMI?  Tomcat is a servlet/JSP engine that listens for HTTP requests on port 8080 by default.

RMI is a totally different protocol that has nothing to do with HTTP.  The RMI daemon uses port 1099 by default.

I'd recommend looking at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check your /etc/hosts file at the server. It should map localhost to 127.0.0.1 and your real hostname to your real IP address. If you have a configuration where you need the other way round, set the system property java.rmi.server.hostname to the correct IP address at the server JVM before exporting the remote object.